# no jar files in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

I am working on a Spring boot project in eclipse and tried to create the project using spring initializr but the maven dependency library is not getting created nor there are any jar files in the .m2 folder. I have tried updating the project and deleting the repository also.

Comment: This doesn't happen and to be honest I have never encountered any such issue. If you can add some screenshots then it would be useful. Remember that when you extract the zip file then you need to import the project as maven project, Have you done that?

Comment: Try `mvn install` or `mvn spring-boot:run` in cmd/terminal

Comment: yes, I have extracted the folder and used as existing maven project. Also, I am working on a company network so that might be an issue but I am not sure and as the jar files are not present, the error: "project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from https://repo.spring.io/libs-release was cached in local repository. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release): repo.spring.io

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. It was a minor mistake in the name of settings.xml; the name should be Settings.xml and that's why the project was not taking to any of the settings.